# How do I animate this text within SwiftUI?

Tags: animation, swiftui

```
var playerView: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Balance: $\(viewModel.balance)")
                .transition(.scale)
            Spacer()
            Text("Player Score: \(viewModel.playerScore)")
            Spacer()
            Text("Bet: $\(viewModel.bet)")
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65))]) {
            ForEach(viewModel.playerCards) { card in
                CardView(card: card, view: self)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNameSpace)
                    .zIndex(zIndex(of: card))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.selectPlayerCard(card)
                    }


            }

        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

I have this playerView and I would like to animate when `viewModel.balance` and `viewModel.bet` changes. But when I throw `.id("balance")... .transition...` nothing happens. I'm not sure how to get it to animate just the changes in `viewModel.balance`. `viewModel.balance` and `viewModel.bet` are being adjusted within the model.

I tried to `withAnimation` it but it didn't work. I tried to throw `.animation(.easeInOut)` and it didn't do anything. It seems that any animation that I throw on it doesn't work.

Comment: Didi you try [`animation(value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:value:))?

Comment: Transitions occur when a view is added/removed from the hierarchy. You could make if showBalance {Text("Balance...}) and toggle the showBalance when viewModel.balance and viewModel.bet change (e.g. using onChange)